# Swift: Pass array of type T to a method taking arrays of T's protocol

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to write a class that has an array of objects conforming to `MyProto`, and I have a method to accept `[MyProto]` for various processing before being added to that array. Here's a playground.

```
protocol MyProto {
    func sayHello()
}

extension MyProto {
    func sayHello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

struct MyStruct: MyProto {
}

class MyClass {
    var protos: [MyProto] = []
    func doSomethingAndThenStore(newProtos: [MyProto]) {
        for proto in newProtos {
            proto.sayHello()
        }
        protos.appendContentsOf(newProtos)
    }
}

let myStructs = [MyStruct(), MyStruct()]
let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.doSomethingAndThenStore(myStructs)
```

On the last line I get an error, `error: cannot convert value of type '[MyStruct]' to expected argument type '[MyProto]'`. If I change it to `myStructs as [MyProto]` the error changes to `error: cannot convert value of type '[MyStruct]' to type '[MyProto]' in coercion`.

How can I pass in my array of concrete types to a method that accepts an array of protocols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem stems from the fact that Swift does not support covariant generics. That is, `Array<Subclass>` is not an `Array<Superclass>`. In this case, even though `MyStruct` is a `MyProto`, `Array<MyStruct>` is not an `Array<MyProto>`.

The reasons why Swift does not support this are somewhat complex, but it boils down to the fact that for some operations, such as array retrieval, treating `Array<MyStruct>` as an `Array<MyProto>` is valid, but for others, such as array insertion, the association actually goes the other way around. You wouldn't be able to insert a `MyProto` into an `Array<MyStruct>`, so `Array<MyStruct>` can't be treated like an `Array<MyProto>`. Other languages have mechanisms for solving this issue, but Swift does not currently support them.

You cannot pass the array directly, but there are several workarounds for this limitation. Most simply, you could map an identity function over the array so that the type checker infers the new type. This will implicitly downcast every element from `MyStruct` to `MyProto` individually:

```
myClass.doSomethingAndThenStore(myStructs.map { $0 })
```

You could alternatively make MyClass generic and add type constraints:

```
class MyClass<T: MyProto> {
    var protos: [T] = []
    func doSomethingAndThenStore(newProtos: [T]) {
        for proto in newProtos {
            proto.sayHello()
        }
        protos.appendContentsOf(newProtos)
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I think I'm going to just add an overload for `doSomethingAndThenStore<T: MyProto>` that does the map and calls the other.